# navigator.geolocation does not return valid timestamp with iOS 6

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, geolocation, ios6

I have some pretty basic GeoLocation code in a browser app, which must report accurate GPS values for both Latitude/Longitude and the TimeStamp.

This has been working in Android devices and with iPhone up to iOS 5.1.1.

Now one of our uses has upgraded to iOS 6.0.1, and the returned timestamps are now all invalid.

The javascript code is of the basic form:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation, { enableHighAccuracy: accuracyVal, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: maxageVal }

function foundLocation(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
var gps_ts =  position.timestamp;
}
```

Android devices continue to return a gps_ts UNIX timestamp that matches the real time, but with iOS 6, we are getting timestamps that translate to odd datetimes ranging in years 1958 to 1969.  They appear to be measuring something chronological, since the values increase with successive uses, but they aren't UNIX timestamps of the current time anymore.

Help with this would be appreciated.  I see that there are other reports with iOS 6 geolocation support (see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4313850?start=0&tstart=0), but nothing specifically about javascript usage and timestamp functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I've been experimenting with this today.  From what I can tell the `timestamp` in iOS is basically 1000 times higher 'resolution' than that of other browsers (microseconds instead of milliseconds).  I wrote a helper function like this to work around it:

```
function getGeoTimestampDate(timestamp) {
    if (timestamp > 14000000000000) { timestamp = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000); }
    return new Date(timestamp);
}
```

I was only able to test on a couple of devices (an original iPad and an iPhone 4, both on iOS 6.0.1) so I'd appreciate it if anyone can confirm if it works on others.